# Azure Web API deployment Cache data

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have written web API in asp.net using .net framework 4.5. The API is hosted in Azure.

Everything works great with my local environment. But when I am hosting this to Azure it works at the time of hosting but next day when I am seeing the data is not updated in Azure and I deploy the API again and it shows correct data.

My immediate suspicion was cache. So I cleaned the cache as per this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-caching-in-web-api/)

It might not be cache issue. Does anyone has any idea about it?

But the issue persist again.

Comment: Can you please explain more on this issue, what code you have added , have you added any type of caching, Does you deployment history of your web api says "succeeded" when you deploy in azure portal. Have you cleared the browser cache,of you web app from where you are using this api. Have you restarted the Web Api. It's not easy to troubleshoot without these details.

Comment: I havent added any caching but I am using ORM Entity Framework. If I am deploying my latest changes are visible but very next day if data changes , API result showing old data. I restarted multiple times but it doesnt fix the issue. But when I am getting old data, I have to deploy the service again and I get result with new data. Restart doesnt help.